# send excel file to client using java servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, apache-poi, export-to-excel

I am using *Apache POI* for generating *Excel* file in *Java Servlets*.

`getExcel()` function returns `HSSFWorkbook`, which I want to send to the client.

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = getExcel();
```

This is what I have tried so far.

```
//block1
ByteArrayOutputStream outByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
wb.write(outByteStream);
byte [] outArray = outByteStream.toByteArray();
response.setContentType("application/ms-excel");
response.setContentLength(outArray.length);
response.setHeader("Expires:", "0");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Demo1.xls");
OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
outStream.write(outArray);
outStream.flush();

//block2
request.setAttribute("Message", str1);
request.setAttribute("MessageDetails", str2);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/MyFile.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Above code sends excel file to the client, but gives me exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
```

If I remove the `block1` or `block2` from above code then it will not give error, but I want to send client `Excel file` and two attributes which I have added to `request` object.

So can send `Excel` file to client using `request.getRequestDispatcher` ? Or is there any better way for doing this?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

**Edit1**
I know why I am getting the `IllegalStateException`, but then my question is how should I send `ExcelFile` and `Request Attributes` both to the client?

**Edit2**
The Reason why I want to send both `Excel file` and `Attributes` to the client is that `MyFile.jsp` has a `<div>` which will show message send from `servlet`.

```
<div style="background-color: aliceblue">
    <h3>${Message}</h3>
</div>
```

**Edit3**
The Reason why I want to send message to client is that I am sending this `Excel file` as an response to `Import Excel operation` in which client will provide `excel file` for inserting data in database, and then I am highlighting the `excel rows` which cannot be inserted due to duplication or any other reasons. So I want to show Import statistics in the `Message` to client and give him copy of excel file with error rows highlighted.

Comment: You can't execute nor a redirect nor a forward when triggering a file download. Just write the content of the file in the response and close the response stream and let the browser takes care of this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send a file from a servlet the "right" way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805859/how-to-send-a-file-from-a-servlet-the-right-way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are flushing your `response` and then trying to `forward`. Container has already sent the `response` back to the client and now is in a dilemma as to how to `forward` the request to another JSP, hence it aborts the operation mid way throwing an Exception. HTTP is a **request-response** model . Once you *request* , you get back a *response* . But once the *response* is already committed the whole transaction is over.

```
outStream.write(outArray); 
// you already committed the response here by flushing the output stream
outStream.flush(); 

//block2
request.setAttribute("Message", str1);
request.setAttribute("MessageDetails", str2);
// this is illegal after you have already flushed the response
request.getRequestDispatcher("/MyFile.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

As per the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29):

> IllegalStateException - if the response was already committed.

**After EDIT1:**

No you cannot do both . You need to decide what you want. Write the bytes to the response setting proper HEADERS and MIME-TYPE. You cannot get the browser download something as well as show a JSP page from the same response.

Comment: Have you tested this? Note my comment on OP's question, then please test this code to see if it really works.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot Thanks for answer, I know why I am getting the `IllegalStateException`, but then my question is how should I send `ExcelFile` and `Request Attributes` both to the client?

Comment: Executing a forward after preparing the response for a file download... OP wants to trigger a file download and a forward, which is not possible and you're not providing a solution either. Note that it is not a dilemma, it is simple: the server won't do any.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza This is OP's code , i have added comments to specify what is happening.

Comment: One not-so-right workaround would be to trigger two requests beforehand to get two responses.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Do you mean to say once the response is flushed , the remaining code in Servlet won't be executed ?

Comment: No, but you won't be able to forward the response or send a redirect.

Comment: @skuntsel Yes that is what I meant . I said *Container has already sent the response back to the client and now is in a dilemma as to how to carry on the forward the request to another JSP* , hence it aborts the operation mid way throwing an exception ! What is wrong in this statement ?